# Emberjs—pass reference of parent component to child in template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am working on an ember 1.13 project an I would like to pass the parent component to its childs in a *.hbs file like so:

```
{{#parent}}
    {{child parent=<what here?>}}
{{/parent}}
```

I have tried to use `{{#parent as |parent|}}` but that does not work. Adding:

```
get parent(){ return this; }
```

to the component definition does not work, too? How can I do that?

**EDIT**

The template for parent looks like:

```
<ul>
    {{yield}}
</ul>
```

And if I write:

```
<ul>
    {{child parent=this}}
    {{yield}}
</ul>
```

works.

It seems I am doing something wrong here, what should be the regular way? Can I make the `parent` at least listen to events from the `child` ??

**EDIT #2**

if I write:

```
<!-- not within the "parent" component's template -->
{{#parent}}
    {{child action=something}}
{{/parent}}
```

I get an error, that the action is not defined in the containing component. Moving the `{{child action=something}}` into the `parent's` template (before the `{{yield}}`) it works. But I would like to include the code above in any other template, how can I do that?

**EDIT #3**

Even if the provided answer is better and cleaner, I could manage to get it running using the `targetObject` property of the child component like so:

```
targetObject: Em.computed.alias('parentView');
```

Comment: `{{child parent=this}}` should work. But why do you need this?

Comment: I would like to configure the `child` with a callback that should triggered if clicked.

Comment: Well, instead of accessing to the parent component, I would prefer to yield actions and data to the child components. As an example, [this](https://github.com/tubitak-bilgem-yte/ember-contextual-table/blob/master/addon/templates/dt-selection-column.hbs#L2) yields an action and some data to the children components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent needs yielding itself:

```
<ul>
    {{yield this}}
</ul>
```

while using it:

```
{{#parent as |p|}}
    {{child parent=p}}
{{/parent}}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I Meanwhile I found another solution… Its in the update…